# ASP.NET MVC Set default controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Please I need to be guided to set a default action for my controllers such that anytime there is no action indicated in a controller, the application will route to the index action on the given controller. For example, if someone navigates to dashboard/ without indicating the action, the application automatically runs the index action of the dashboard controller.

The following shows my attempts but it is still not working.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
      routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Regular",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "ControllerDefault",
      url: "{controller}",
      defaults: new {  action = "Index"}
    );
  }
}
```

I will appreciate any guide to get it working right,

Comment: First of all, MVC Routing examines the routes in the order they are added. The first two routes in your code have exactly the same configuration, so the `Regular` route will never be reached, nor the third one that is contained in the above ones. I suggest that if you want to redirect to a login page when somebody enter to your site, do it from an authentication filter, and do not use the routing as it is not its purpose.

Comment: My problem is not setting a default controller. Its rather setting a default method for every controller.
I want to make Index method to be called in any controller if no method is indicated.
That's what I am looking for

Comment: Then, use the default route that MVC template provides. Michael Berezin has posted it in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to different route on the same url.
you only need to use the default route.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home",action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

you can change "Home" to "Dashboard" if that is your default controller.

Comment: My problem is not setting a default controller. Its rather setting a default method for every controller.
I want to make Index method to be called in any controller if no method is indicated.

Comment: that route does that.the definition of the route is:
if {controller} is empty use "Home"
if {action} is empty use "index"
if {id} has value place in the id parameter.

for every url that has only the controller name, the request should go the index action.